# delete elements from lists in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I am using python, I have a nested list like this

```
sequences_list = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

I want to get a sort of sequences like this

```
sequences_list = [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

this is my code

```
k = 1
j = 0
while (k <= len(sequences_list)):
    del sequences_list[j][k:]
    k = k+1
    j = j+1
print(sequences_list)
```

the result i get is

```
[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
```

Comment: Are you sure? I'm getting your expected result when I run your code.

Comment: `sequences_list  = [ i[:k] for k,i in enumerate(sequences_list,1)]`?

Comment: The problem is not visible in what you posted, but I'm quite sure it is created at the moment you *define* the original `sequences_list`. You probably just copied the same sublist.

Comment: Yep - you probably did something like `sequences_list = [[1,2,3,4,5]] * 5` wich creates 5 references to the same list so you modify the same data  behind all these references to the same data

Comment: `[sequences_list[i][:i+1] for i in range(len(sequences_list))]`

Comment: You are handling the same reference. Use `sequence_list = [ [1,2,3,4,5] for _ in range(5)]` to get different lists inside sequence_list - then your code works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one

```
    sequences_list = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

    print([element[0:po+1] for po,element in enumerate(sequences_list)])
```